# Vaadin TextField: how to disable underline?

Tags: css, vaadin, polymer-3.x

Vaadin text field has a default underline. I want to remove it.
I am using it inside of a Vaadin combo box.

In dev tools I can see that a div with the attribute `part="input-field"` is the cause.
Setting it to `display: none;` works in the browser.
I can't seem to target it with code. I've tried the following:

```
`[part="input-field"] {
     display: none !important;
 }
 .vaadin-text-field-container [part="input-field"] {
     display: none !important;
 }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [Viritin](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/viritin) add-on (use latest version) to your project, and configure:

```
TextField field = new MTextField().withSpellCheckOff();
```

OR

you can use the low level API to configure the html element:

```
new HtmlElementPropertySetter(yourTextInputComponent).setProperty(
                "spellcheck", false);
```

Comment: I've updated my question. And also I can't add libraries to the project. It must be lean as as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding this module to the HTML file. 
I placed this above the first script tag in the file.

```
<dom-module id="vaadin-text-field-module" theme-for="vaadin-text-field">
<template>
  <style>
    div::before, div::after {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</template>
```

`:before` is the underline before the input has a value and `:after` is the line after.
Therefore this would disable both.
`[part="input-field"]` disabled the input and the value was not seen after selection.